# Formula inside of regex pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I can use variable inside of pattern, such as

```
if ($param =~ /^${param}$/)
```

But how can I use a formula inside of pattern, to get something like this (incorrect syntax) >>

```
if ($param =~ /^0*{param+0}$/)
```

Possible..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interpolate the results of arbitrary expression via the *shopping-cart pseudooperator* `@{[ ... ]}`. The derererence operators like `@{ ... }` can contain an arbitrary code block. Just make sure that the last statement evaluates to an array reference (or with `${ ... }`: scalarref).

As an example:

```
my ($foo, $bar, $baz) = (3, 5, 7);
local $_ = "22, oh whatever";
if (/^@{[ $foo * $bar + $baz ]}.+whatever/) { say "ok" }
```

---

#### Edit

While the above solution works for any interpolating quote operatos (`qq`, `qr`, `qx`), regexes have an extra possibility to embed code: The `(??{ ... })`. The difference is *when* the code is evaluated:

- `@{[ ... ]}` evaluates the code when the Perl statement is run/at pattern compile time
- `(??{ ... })` evaluates the code when that position in the pattern is reached. The result is then used as a pattern. This means that the code may be evaluated multiple times per match, due to backtracking.

In this case, the pattern

```
/^(??{ $foo * $bar + $baz }).+whatever/
```

would be equivalent to the above regex, as no backtracking over the pattern generated by the code can happen.

Comment: Yes! I knew Perl can do it :) And I knew some smart guru will come and answer this question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can't put executable Perl code in a regex pattern (although you can put it in a replacement string with the `/e` modifier.) What you can do instead is build up your pattern dynamically:

```
my $number = $foo * $bar + $baz;
if ( $param =~ /^${number}.+whatever/ ) { ... }
```

Comment: Not possible the way you want to do it, right. That's probably a good thing, considering what some Perl regexes look like already. :)